# Is there a way to add a class to non current menu item?

Tags: functions, theme-development, menus

When using the `wp_nav_menu` function, the current menu item markup usually is like so:

```
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-19">
    <a href="http://domain.com/page-name/">Page Name</a>
</li>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a class to the non current item on the menu when there's an item selected. Something like `non-current-menu-item`.

It would add some very interesting css possibilities.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [menu_walker()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

Comment: Thank you so much @dingo_d! I wasn't aware of this class. I managed to make it work exactly the way I wanted. I'll answer this question so other people will be able to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup of the `wp_nav_menu` can be totally customized by using the [`Walker`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) class.

Here's the code I used:

functions.php

```
class Walker_Menu extends Walker {

    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 
        'id'     => 'db_id' 
    );

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        if (is_front_page()) {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li id='menu-item-%s'><a href='%s'>%s</a></li>\n",
            sanitize_title($item->title),
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
        }
        else {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li id='menu-item-%s'%s><a href='%s'>%s</a></li>\n",
            sanitize_title($item->title),
            ( $item->object_id == get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current-menu-item"' : 'class="non-current-menu-item"',
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );
        }
    }

}
```

header.php

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'    => 'Main Menu',
    'walker'  => new Walker_Menu()
));
```

It add the class non-current-menu-item to every li element but the current menu item, and it will not do so on the front page.

Huge thanks to dingo_d for pointing out the class!